# Authentication error with local website Flutter Dart

Tags: http, authentication, dart

I have an internal website that uses login page then summary page

when i put the login page in the http.get it return 200 authentication succeeded but it doesn't retrieve any information

when i put the link for the summary page (that have the information i need) in the http.get authentication fail and return 401

i use basic Authentication

do you have any advice ?

```
Future getCPUData() async{

    var client = http.Client();
    String username = 'xxx';
    String password = 'xxx';
    String basicAuth = ('$username:$password');
    print(basicAuth);

    http.Response sAppLoginURL = await http.get('http://1.1.1.1/app/Login.aspx?autologin=no',
      headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});

    print(sAppLoginURL.statusCode);
    print(sAppLoginURL.body);

    var document = parse(sAppLoginURL.body);
    List<html.Element> links = document.querySelectorAll('td.Proprety > a.hostname');

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> linkMap = [];
      for (var link in links) {
      linkMap.add({
      'Proprety': link.text,
      'hostname': link.attributes['hostname'],
    });
     print(linkMap);
     print(links);
     return json.encode(linkMap);
    }

    }
```

it print 200 when i use the login page but i get nothing from it
when i change the link to the page i want to get the data from
http://1.1.1.1/app/SummaryView.aspx?ViewID=1

it gives me auth faild 401

Comment: also with String basicAuth = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));

Comment: is there anyone here ?